# What http error code to return when "ETag" header field is malformed?

Tags: http, http-error, etag

[RFC 7232](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7232.html#header.etag) states the format of the If-Match and If-None-Match header fields. What http error code should be returned when the format of the header is wrong? 412 precondiction failed or 400 bad request? The RFC speaks only about "evaluate the If-Match precondition".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`400`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) is the appropriate status code here, since this is a case of "malformed request syntax". `412` would be a misleading response, since the client wouldn't know there was anything wrong with how it formatted its request.

Comment: I think this is correct only if the header itself is malformed. If the etag is *valid* from a HTTP perspective, but *invalid* from your application perspective, the current response might still be 412. But if there's too many `"` characters (for example) 400 is right.

Comment: @Evert: I agree. I take "RFC 7232 states the format..." to be a reference to the formal grammar given in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both but i think than 412 will be the most precise and correct.

MDN use specifically ETag as exemple of HTTP Code 412

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412

Comment: MDN says "when the condition is not fulfilled". Is it possible to test the condition if it is not in the correct format? What is returned in general if a header format is not correct?